# How to simulate Azure VM backup failure

Tags: azure, backup

How can I simulate a backup failure on Azure VM?
The Backup job executes fine every day.
In order to test an alert execution I need to fail the VM backup.

I tried to kill the Volume Shadow Copy process on the VM during a manually triggered backup, but it didn't cause the back to fail.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: shutdown the vm in the middle of the backup?

Comment: How did it go for you? Did you manage to do what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Put a delete lock on the Resource Group containing the backups, the name of the group should be something like: AzureBackupRG_eastus2_1
Then run your backup a couple of times and the backup should eventually fail because it cant remove the oldest backup.

Another way to do it is to block all outbound traffic in your NSG.

Answer (score 0):

Backup failure occurs when a backup of a VM is initiated twice, one right after the other.
Because there could be only one backup running at a time, the second one fails with an error, which is sufficient to trigger the alert.